# Corruption of menus in Windows app

Tags: windows, sdk, wxwidgets

I'm the author of a Windows application that's been around for years. The app uses the wxWidgets UI library. For the newest version, we upgraded to the Microsoft c++ compiler in Studio 10 and to the latest Windows SDK library. We did not change much else in the app. Now, several users have reported that after a period of time running the app, the menus go crazy. All of the users reporting the problem are running on Windows XP. The menus either get huge, filling the screen, and have a giant italic font with strikethroughs. Or they get really small, so that the only thing shown are up and down arrows, suggesting the rendering code thinks the screen real estate is too small to display anything else.

You can find example screen shots here:

[image: menu2.jpg]

[image: menu3.jpg]

Once the menus go crazy, all menus are affected, except the standard Windows and MDI menus. The only way to recover is to restart the app.

The code in the app and wxWidgits is a thin layer on top of the standard Windows API. Once the menus are created, afaik Windows manages the rendering.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: My first hypothesis would be that there is a resource leak somewhere. Can your users encountering this problem look at the GDI resources column in the task manager and check if it has a reasonable value (I'd say a few hundreds at most)?